# Use wait_for() in button

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@commands.command(name='e')
async def edit(self, ctx):
    firstbutton = Button(label="test")
    await ctx.send('test', components=[firstbutton])
    def check(m): return interaction.component.label == 'test'
    interaction = await self.bot.wait_for("button_click", check=check)
    if interaction.component.label == 'test':
        await ctx.send(content='Clicked')
```

The Button and the message does show up, but the button have no action when clicked.

Edited:Packages

```
import json, discord, random, datetime, asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import utils
import discord
from discord_components import *
```

Comment: Are there any errors shown in the console? If it is please provide them.

Comment: Which package are you using?

Comment: No Errors were given.
I added the imports.

Answer (score 1):

In your `check()` method you have taken the interaction as `m` but you are trying to access the `label` attribute of `interaction` which is not yet defined.

```py
@commands.command()
async def edit(self, ctx):
    firstbutton = Button(label="test")
    await ctx.send('test', components=[firstbutton])
    def check(m): 
        return m.component.label == 'test'
    interaction = await self.bot.wait_for("button_click", check=check)
    if interaction.component.label == 'test':
        await ctx.send(content='Clicked')
```

Also you mentioned that you didn't get any errors, you might want to set up [logging](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging.html#logging-setup) for discord. It will help you debugging.

For discord-ui:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_ui import Components, Button, UI

import discord

@bot.command()
async def edit(ctx):
    firstbutton = Button(label="test")
    msg = await ctx.send('test', components=[firstbutton])

    def check(m):
        return m.component.label == 'test'
    interaction = await msg.wait_for("button", bot, check=check)
    if interaction.component.label == 'test':
        await ctx.send(content='Clicked')
```

Comment: Whoops, It did not work. Again, No Errors were given.

Comment: For some reason the `name` attribute in `commands.command()` wasn't working properly so the command wasn't recognised. Now the command is recognised, but the interaction fails. I checked the logs the API doesn't recognise the `INTERACTION_CREATE` for some reason. You might want to switch to `discord-ui` instead, I tried the near identical code there and it works. Well, somewhat. The interaction still says failed but the 'Clicked.' message is sent and it works, it just shows an error on discord that's not even on the logs. I'm stumped as well, sorry couldn't help you more.

Comment: It's fine, I will try figure it myself. If I found a answer I will post it back here